# Photoshop CS6 will not allow me to choose Shape colour

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, shapes

I've just begun using Photoshop CS6 and encountered a problem I've never had before.
1. Went to Custom Shapes Tool, chose a shape, selected a colour (now shows in foreground).
2. Top bar shows from left: Custom Shape Icon, Option chosen is Shape (not Pixels or Path), Fill block - shows the colour I specified: maroon, Stroke block set to None.
3. With crosshair cursor, I click, shape appears correctly on layer but with a GREEN colour.
4. Foreground colour shows my maroon colour, so does Fill block on top bar, as well as Colour Picker when I click on Shape layer.
5. No matter what I do, I cannot fill with my chosen colour, repeatedly shows green.
6. Tried to rasterise shape and recolour, still shows green.
7. Tried to choose another colour on Swatches palette, gives me a purple. No matter what colour I choose, it gives another colour.
PLEASE HELP. I CANNOT GET MY WORK DONE.
I increased RAM 3 days ago - was 4GB now 6GB. Surely this would not have affected my Apps?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer by checking all my layers.
My layers are very organised, in groups etc.
Within one of my CLOSED LAYER GROUPS, ABOVE THE SHAPE LAYER I was working on, was a hue and saturation layer.
This was affecting the colour I was trying to specify.
So simple, yet so frustrating.
And there I was thinking my new Photoshop CS6 was somehow corrupt and would have to be re-loaded.
Apologies to anyone reading this and trying to work on an answer.